# How to query comma separated String

Tags: swift, realm

Example:

```
class MyObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var linkedServerIds: String?
}
```

The `linkedServerIds` *may* contain comma separated `String`. example:

```
linkedServerIds = "18305,13423,11539,11234"
```

Currently if we want objects that `linkedServerIds` contains `13423` OR `11234` we do:

```
Results<MyObject>.filter({
    if let linkedServerIds =  $0.linkedServerIds?.components(separatedBy: ","),
        linkedServerIds.contains(where: { ["13423", "11234"].contains($0) }) {
        return true
    }
    return false
})
```

This filter will return `Array` of `MyObject` and not `Results<MyObject>`

Is it possible to perform similar filter using `NSPredicate`? So we can keep the return in `Results<MyObject>`

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with realm, however your NSPredicate should be something like this.

```
NSPredicate(format: linkedServerIds CONTAINS %@, ["13423","11234"])
```

Obviously, replacing "["13423","11234"]" with whatever argument you are evaluating.